# SwiftData SwiftUI: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Any>' (0x1df9c31f8) to 'Foundation.UUID' (0x1dfa27d58)

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am using very simple code to delete items from list getting through swiftData. The below shows the minimum reproducible example.

```
@Model
class ShoppingItem {
    
    var id: UUID
    var quantity: String
    var name: String
    var measuringUnit: String
    var isChecked: Bool
    var createAt: Date
    
    init(id: UUID, quantitly: String, name: String, measuringUnit: String, isChecked: Bool, createAt: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.quantity = quantitly
        self.name = name
        self.measuringUnit = measuringUnit
        self.isChecked = isChecked
        self.createAt = createAt
    }
}

class ShoppingListView { 
var shoppingItems = [ShoppingItem]()

}

func fetchData() {
            shoppingItems = []
            do {
                let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<ShoppingItem>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
                shoppingItems = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
            } catch {
                print("Fetch failed")
            }
        }

func deleteItem(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem) {
            modelContext.delete(shoppingItem)
        }
```

This code work perfectly fine instead of one case.

If we have 2 similar items in the list then the code crashed with this error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Any>' (0x1df9c31f8) to 'Foundation.UUID' (0x1dfa27d58).
```

and show this error line in the model class.
[image]

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  
In particular show the code for your `model class`. The code you show is **not** a minimum reproducible example. The error you show does not correspond to any of the code you are showing us.

Comment: Actually the issue it if we have same name of items then its start crashing.

Comment: Show us how ShoppingItem is defined and the code for selecting the object to delete and how the deleteItem function is called.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting a SwiftData object takes two steps: calling `delete()` on your model context, passing in the object you want to delete, then saving the changes, either with an explicit call to `save()` or waiting for the autosave to trigger if you have it enabled.
Found the solution for here [How to delete a SwiftData object](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-delete-a-swiftdata-object)

so I just modify my delete function is it works.

```
func deleteItem(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem) {
    modelContext.delete(shoppingItem)

    do {
        try  modelContext.save()
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer can not possibly have anything to do with the error message in the question.